# Inline variable assignment results not always showing in Chrome/Edge Dev Tools debugger while stepping through

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When stepping through code in Chrome/Edge Dev Tools debugger, I've sometimes seen inline variable values show up to the right of the code, making it easier to see what the variable contents are than having to set them each up in the watch list.  But more often these inline values don't show up. Why do they sometimes show and sometimes don't? I'd like to see them always.

Likewise, it doesn't show the value when hovering over or even clicking on the variable, and other times it does.

[image]

And yes, the inline variable display option *is* enabled:

[image]